# Ошибка: "Не используйте пустые наборы правил css"

Tags: css, angular

Хочу стилизовать все теги input в app.component.css:

```
input {
    &.ng-invalid {
       border: 1px solid red; 
    }
}
```

Идёт подчёркивание и подсказка типа - Не используйте пустые
наборы правил css. Что не так, помогите разобраться? Ну и не
работает стилизация. Работаю в VS Code.

Comment: Но `css` не принимает стили `scss/sass` попробуйте написать `input.ng-invalid  { border: 1px solid red;} ` должно работать.

Comment: Да, работает, спасибо большое!